# Differential of $\log$ mapping on manifolds and Lie groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a finite dimensional $C^\infty$-manifold and $\nabla$ is an affine connection on $M$, we know that exponential mapping and logarithm mapping are well-defined locally. Fix a point $p_0\in M$, $\log_{p_0}(\cdot):M\to T_{p_0} M$ is well-defined on a neighborhood of $p_0$. Now my questions are:

1. Is $\log_{p_0}(\cdot)$ differentiable or differentiable almost everywhere? If it is, is there a closed form?
2. Intuitively, I guess that it's the parallel transport from $T_p M$ to $T_{p_0}M$, where $p$ represents the argument. Is this correct in general? Does it hold in any special cases?

So far, I mainly focus on two cases, but I welcome any more general results.

1. $M$ is a Riemannian manifold and $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection.
2. $M$ is a Lie group and $\nabla$ represents the canonical left-invariant connection, so the exponential mapping is the usual one on Lie group.

Please enlighten me with any related results, examples or references. Thank you!

Comment: Is $exp$ defined by solving $\nabla_{\dot \gamma} \dot \gamma = 0$?

Comment: @Arctic Char Yes.

Comment: As you said, log is only locally defined. What do you mean by "almost everywhere"? In which domain? Maybe you are asking if the cut-locus of a point has measure zero? Regarding (2): No, log is not the parallel transport, not even intuitively.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan When M is a orientable Riemannian manifold, there's a measure generated by the integral of continuous functions, through riesz representation theorem. And by (2), I mean the differential of log, not log itself. But you've made good points. I'll revise my statement later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a note on the logarithmic map, which isn't really a single map at all, but a family of local inverses of the exponential map.

The exponential map $\exp_{p_0}$ as full rank at $0\in T_{p_0}M$, so by inverse function theorem there are open sets $\mathcal{U}\subseteq T_{p_0}M$, $\mathcal{V}\subseteq M$ such that $\exp_{p_0}:\mathcal{U}\to\mathcal{V}$ is a diffeomorphism. There isn't a canonical choice of neighborhood $\mathcal{U}$. Having chosen such an appropriate $\mathcal{U}$, there is a corresponding local inverse $\log_{p_0}:\mathcal{V}\to\mathcal{U}$ which is certainly differentiable *on its domain*, and it's differential at every point is the inverse of $d\exp_{p_0}$. It isn't possible to extend this local inverse to a global one, however, unless $\exp_p$ is a diffeomorphism.

Fixing a particular choice of domain $\mathcal{U}$, we can compare the two maps you're interested in by looking at their inverses. Fix $v\in\mathcal{U}$, and let $p=\exp_{p_0}(v)$.

For simplicity, I'll identify $T_vT_{p_0}M$ with $T_{p_0}M$ in the standard way. Rather that look at $d_p\log_{p_0}$, it is simpler to consider its inverse $d_v\exp_{p_0}:T_{p_0}M\to T_p M$. We can equivalently compare this to the parallel transportation $F:T_{p_0}M\to T_pM$ along the the geodesic $\gamma$ starting at $v$. These two maps are not generally the same. A detailed comparison between them is made in [this mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126104/difference-between-parallel-transport-and-derivative-of-the-exponential-map). (Though only in the Riemannian case; I suspect the presence of torsion will show up in the Jacobi equation.)

As an alternative intuition for the problem, one can think of $d_v\exp_{p_0}$ as describing how an infinitesimal change in the initial velocity of a geodesic causes its endpoint to move. $d_{p}\log_{p_0}$ is then the inverse, it takes an infinitesimal displacement of the endpoint and determines what change in velocity would bring about this displacement. This can be made precise using [Jacobi fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_field).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just found a expression of [derivative of the exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map). So is there a closed form of the inverse? I don't know much about Jacobi field.

Comment: What do you mean by closed form here? As far as I know, "closed form" is really only meaningful in a chosen set of coordinates, where $\exp$ and $\log$ are defined by differential equations which need not have closed form solutions.

Comment: @Selene I'm a bit late, but I know of a nice trick that might be useful to you. Namely, denoting $d_g^{p} (q) \equiv d_g(p, \, q)$ as the geodesic map defined about a point $p \in M$, the logarithm at $q$ can be expressed as $\log_{q}(p) = - d_g^{p}(q) \, \left[\nabla d_g^{p}\right] \vert_{q}$, where $\nabla$ is the gradient.

Comment: @tommym Thanks. I already found some relevant reference.